# Starting a virtual machine with vmrun

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vmware-workstation

For some reason, when I start an ubuntu virtual machine using vmrun, it has no network connection, but when I start it within the vmware workstation gui it does.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When starting the virtual machine with the command line after using the gui, it prompts you asking if you copied it or moved it.  If you choose move it, networking seems to work.